# Непонятный вывод на экран значения конструкции switch

Tags: php, switch

В результате данного кода:

```
<?php
    $day = 0;

 switch ($day<=5 && $day>=1) {

case $day:
    echo "Это число больше 0, но меньше 5";
    break;
}
?>
```

выводится "Это число больше 0, но меньше 5". Но почему? Ведь `0` не попадает в интервал, заданный в `switch`

Comment: как вы думаете, что в данном выражении `switch ($day<=5 && $day>=1)` находится?

Comment: думал уже и не пойму. Но даже при выражении $day<=5 && $day>0 всё равно тот же результат выводит.

Comment: А, прошу прощение, надо так $day<=5 && $day>=0

Comment: Быть того не может

Comment: тут разобрались. Спасибо. При $day<=5 && $day>=0 не выводит на экран ничего.

Comment: Как не надо задавать вопросы...

Comment: @Sven, тебе дали верный ответ.

Comment: `При $day<=5 && $day>=0 не выводит на экран ничего` - логично, потому что условий больше нет в case. и `default` тоже отсутствует

Comment: Советую почитать, как работает switch. Уже второй очень странный вопрос от Вас про него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switch (true && false)`  Результат false, т.е. 0, а так как переменная `$day = 0;`  отсюда и вывод данного кейса